# Integrating over the distribution of a function (Lebesgue integral)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $F(b)=\mu(\{ t \in [T, 2T]: \ln| f(2+it)| \geq b\})$.
$$ \int_{T}^{2T} |f(2+it)|^2 dt= -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2b} dF(b).$$
Can someone help explain how we get the integral on the RHS? I know that we can write $|f(2+it)|^2 = e^{\ln |f(2+it)|^2} = e^{2 \ln |f(2+it)|}.$  I read about Lebesgue integrals and tried applying what I know, but I am stuck. I don’t get why there is a negative sign, how we get an infinite integral, etc. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $g(t)=|f(2+it)|^{2}$. Show that $\int \phi (t) d\mu \circ g^{-1}(t)=-\int \phi (b)dF(b)$ for all non-negative measurable functions $\phi$ by first checking that this holds when $\phi$ is the charcateristic function of an interval $(a,b]$. [You can then pass to finite disjoint unions of such intervals and then  use standard measure theoretic arguments to show that the equation holds for all non-negative measurable functiosn $\phi$]. Now you get your result by taking $\phi (t)=e^{2t}$.

Comment: Hi Kavi, thank you for the hint. Did you mean $\int g(t) d \mu(t) = - \int \phi(b) dF(b)$? Also, when you say “characteristic function”, is that the same as the indicator function? I will have to think about your hint… I’m not competent enough to follow your hint right away! :( Thank you though.

Comment: I have corrected the equation. Yes, characteristic function (used in measure theory) is same as indicator function (used in Probability Theory). @blueskyscroll

Comment: Ah okay! Thank you. Lastly, is that the change of variable formula in probability?? I had a hard time understanding that proof, but it seems relevant to my problem so I must try harder. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is a change of variable formula.  @blueskyscroll

Comment: Okay, I don’t see why we have a negative, but I will focus now and think about it. THANK YOU SO MUCH! :)

Comment: @blueskyscroll In the defintion of $F(b)$ if we had $\leq b$ on the right side (which is standard way of defining distribution functions in Probablity Theory) then we wouldn't have the minus sign.

Comment: Right! thank you for that second hint :)